# HOW TO MEARGE THE 'listBulleted' ELEMENT WHILE COMING CONSCUTVELY

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, xslt-2.0

**The element 'listBulleted' have same parent and here we are trying to mearge only those 'listBulleted' elements which have conscutive/countinued otherwise keep as it is:**

**NOTE: We are creating specific '<xsl:template match="listBulleted">' template so we can easely moved/add in other xslt.**

**INPUT XML:**
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<listBulleted>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Design.</emphasis> Approval of the specific design of the tiebacks or underpinning.</para>
        <listBulleted>
            <listItem><para flow="new">The location of the tiebacks.</para></listItem>
            <listItem><para flow="new">The design of underpinning will be critical.</para></listItem>
        </listBulleted></listItem>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Design Professionals and Contractors.</emphasis>.</para></listItem>
</listBulleted>
<listBulleted>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Means of Installation.</emphasis> Approval of the timing.</para></listItem>
</listBulleted>
<listBulleted>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Liability for Damages.</emphasis> The constructing party’s.</para></listItem>
</listBulleted>
<listBulleted>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Adjacent Property Owner’s Rights</emphasis></para>
        <listBulleted>
            <listItem><para flow="new">An acknowledgment by the constructing party.</para></listItem>
            <listItem><para flow="new">Assurances for the constructing party.</para></listItem>
            <listItem><para flow="new">The assurances described in the preceding recorded.</para></listItem>
        </listBulleted></listItem>
</listBulleted>
<listBulleted>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Insurance.</emphasis> Description.</para></listItem>
</listBulleted>
</root>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<listBulleted>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Design.</emphasis> Approval of the specific design of the tiebacks or underpinning.</para>
        <listBulleted>
            <listItem><para flow="new">The location of the tiebacks.</para></listItem>
            <listItem><para flow="new">The design of underpinning will be critical.</para></listItem>
        </listBulleted></listItem>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Design Professionals and Contractors.</emphasis>.</para></listItem>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Means of Installation.</emphasis> Approval of the timing.</para></listItem>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Liability for Damages.</emphasis> The constructing party’s.</para></listItem>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Adjacent Property Owner’s Rights</emphasis></para>
        <listBulleted>
            <listItem><para flow="new">An acknowledgment by the constructing party.</para></listItem>
            <listItem><para flow="new">Assurances for the constructing party.</para></listItem>
            <listItem><para flow="new">The assurances described in the preceding recorded.</para></listItem>
        </listBulleted></listItem>
    <listItem><para flow="new"><emphasis bold="yes">Insurance.</emphasis> Description.</para></listItem>
</listBulleted>
</root>
```

**XSLT CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="listBulleted">
    <listBulleted>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::node()[1][self::listBulleted]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::node()[1][self::listBulleted]/node()"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </listBulleted>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="listBulleted[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::listBulleted]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Reference URL :** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1S8Az/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text book approach is `group-adjacent`:

```
<xsl:template match="*[listBulleted]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent=". instance of element(listBulleted)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/node()"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1S8Az/2

It doesn't match on `listBulleted`, however, as that is not the container where you need to group.

Comment: Thank you! Martin i will check and let you know.